# StructureMap to Ninject conversion

Tags: c#, ninject, structuremap

How can I convert this:

```
For<ISession>().Use(ctx => {
    var uow = (INHibernateUnitOfWork)ctx.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>();
    return uow.Session;
});
```

To Ninject?

I was able to convert this:

```
For<ISessionSource>().Singleton().Use<NHibernateSessionSource>();
```

To

```
Bind<ISessionSource>()
    .To<NHibernateSessionSource>()
    .InSingletonScope()
```

And I think I was able to convert this one as well:

```
For<IUnitOfWork>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<NHibernateUnitOfWork>();
```

To

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<NHibernateUnitOfWork>().InThreadScope();
```

I know that these are not all going to be one-to-one, but could I get some help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(ctx => {
    var uow = (INHibernateUnitOfWork)ctx.Kernel.Get<IUnitOfWork>();
    return uow.Session;
});
```